# unable to parse application/octet-stream into image in node js

Tags: node.js, buffer, exif

i am new to node js. i am trying to make a rest api call and get an image and store locally/read it for exif data

```
app.post('/getEXIF', async function (pagereq, pageres) {
try  {
  var fs = require('fs');
  let res = await superagent
  .get('https://abcd.com/service')
  .set("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .set("Authorization", "Bearer mytokenvvvvvvvv")
  .set("accept", "application/octet-stream")
  .buffer(true).disableTLSCerts();
  fs.writeFile('a.jpg',res.text,function (err) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
});
  
 }
catch(error) {
  console.log("error " + error);
}
});
```

It writing the image but not opening (unsupported format). My ultimate aim is to read the data as buffer for processing EXIF information. The exif libraries all i used (EXIFR, EXIF, EXIFParser) says given input is not image or buffer or a file etc.

Also i am not able to save the response data as an image first. If am able to parse the octet-steam into buffer , then i can write or read from that.

When i hit the service with postman, i am able to save the file as .jpeg and image works. But the raw content is some thing like this (first couple of lines)

����\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00��\x00�\x00\t\x06\x07\x12\x13\x12\x15\x13\x13\x13\x16\x16\x15\x15\x18\x19\x1A\x17\x18\x18\x19\x18\x1A\x1B\x1B\x1D\x1A\x18\x17\x1E\x1A\x18\x1A\x1D\x1A\x1E)!\x18\x1D%\x1D\x1D\x18!1"%*+...\x1A\x1F383,7(-.+\x01\n

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

I just found my solution which is working.

```
function binaryParser(res, callback) {
    res.setEncoding('binary');
    res.data = '';
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        res.data += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function () {
        callback(null, new Buffer(res.data, 'binary'));
    });
}

var fs = require('fs');
let res = await superagent
.get('https://abcd.com?getEXIF')
.set("Content-Type", "application/json")
.set("Authorization", "Bearer sdfdsf")
.set("accept", "application/octet-stream")
.buffer()
.parse(binaryParser)
.end(function(err, res) {
    if (err){
        pageres.send(err);
    }
    //binary response data is in res.body as a buffer
    console.log("res=", res.body);
    });
```